# Can a function initialize a variable in PHP?

Tags: php, variables

Without specifically doing so,

Like:

```
function init($var){
  $var = 'x';
}

function a(){
  init($foo);

  echo $foo; // should be x

}
```

Something like the list() function :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Pass by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php):

```
function init(&$var){
  $var = 'x';
}
```

Comment: I had the link I edited into your answer in my clipboard in preparation for _my_ answer. Seeing as you've answered this already, I decided to put it to some use.

Comment: thanks, didn't think of that :p Can the `&$var` argument be optional? Because I tried to check if the argument is false and it doesn't seem to assign it

Comment: @Alex: How would it be optional and still have it assigned a value?

Comment: I mean, if it's not present, then don't create the variable :)

Comment: @Alex - Provide a default value of `null` for the parameter: `function init(&$var = null)`.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. You can pass the parameter by [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php). So you have to change this

```
function init($var)
```

into this:

```
function init(&$var)
```